# Android rxJava Error handling with retrofit

Tags: java, android, error-handling, retrofit, rx-java

I'm using the newer RX java where instead of

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribeFunc<T>() {...});
```

this is used: (due to deprecation)

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<T>() {...});
```

(This can be important as most example, tutorial, explonation uses the old one...)

Well, lets see my problem. I have a Java class, relevant parts from it:

```
private interface ApiManagerService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/login")
    User getUser(@Field("username") String userName, @Field("password") String password);

}


private static RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(HOST)
    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
    .build();

private static ApiManagerService apiManager = restAdapter.create(ApiManagerService.class);

public static Subscription login(final String userName, final String password, Observer<User> observer) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<User>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super User> subscriber) {
            try {

                User user = apiManager.getUser(userName, password);

                subscriber.onNext(user);
                subscriber.onCompleted();

            } catch (RetrofitError e) {
                subscriber.onError(e);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }
        }
    }

    ).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .retry(3)
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .subscribe(observer);
}
```

This code almost works perfectly, if everything is ok. But if I make an intentional error, like I turn off the WiFi.. than retrofit get the **"UnKnownHostException"**... as it should happen at the retrofit call (getUser) in the try catch block. But instead of handling the error to onError(Throwable t) --> where I could handle, it just crashes the app. So it is like if the error never gets to the catch block. 
What is strange that HTTP errors (like 404, 401 etc.) is catched, got by onError(...) and everything is just fine.

Everything goes for 3 times before crash, as of .retry(3) but none gets into catch clause.

**EDIT 1**

LogCat Output:

```
    01-08 16:19:31.576  15285-16162/asd.bdef.gh D/Retrofit﹕ ---- ERROR https://testapi.com/api/login
    01-08 16:19:31.606  15285-16162/asd.bdef.gh D/Retrofit﹕ java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "testapi.com": No address associated with hostname
                at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:394)
                at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
                at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
                at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
                at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:259)
                at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:233)
                at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextUnconnected(RouteSelector.java:159)
                at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:133)
                at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:314)
                at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:237)
                at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:423)
                at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:105)
                at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:239)
                at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
                at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
                at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.prepareRequest(UrlConnectionClient.java:68)
                at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:37)
                at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:321)
                at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
                at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$1.invoke(RestAdapter.java:265)
                at retrofit.RxSupport$2.run(RxSupport.java:55)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
                at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    01-08 16:19:31.606  15285-16162/asd.bdef.gh D/Retrofit﹕ ---- END ERROR
    01-08 16:19:31.977  15285-15285/asd.bdef.gh D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    01-08 16:19:31.977  15285-15285/asd.bdef.gh W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c9d8b0)
    01-08 16:19:31.977  15285-15285/asd.bdef.gh E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

the given api address is not the real one, but the real one is reachable. I just turned off the WiFi to test error handling.

And one more use-case: If I add to the observable .onExceptionResumeNext([2nd observable]) than it goes to the 2nd observable, and it not crashes. But this is not the solution of the problem.

**EDIT 2**

```
ApiManager.login(userName, pass, new Observer<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() { }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        DialogManager.showBasicErrorDialog(getApplicationContext(), e.getLocalizedMessage());
        logger.showLog("Login Not ok");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(User user) {
        logger.showLog("login ok, user: " + user.getName().toString());
        {...}
    }

});
```

EDIT 3

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
rx.exceptions.OnErrorFailedException: Error occurred when trying to propagate error to Observer.onError
        at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:175)
        at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:97)
        at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:144)
```

{...}

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'rx.functions.Action0 rx.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$TimedAction.action' on a null object reference
        at rx.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:85)
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Could you post your stack trace/logcat output? What does the calling code look like (the observer definition)?

Comment: It has been edited.. but actually it is not too relevant, as the error is on purpose. ...

Comment: The above output is _not your app crashing_ - it's [Retrofit logging the error](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/2c1c6ec370f88e21ac219d8f343f1f6d904c1c87/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RestAdapter.java#L495). Do you have a logcat filter enabled?...

Comment: Looks like [`retry(long count)`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/Observable.java#L6184) won't propagate the error - so it seems like all this code is working as intended/as documented, and the crash is occurring after this.

Comment: Can you post the code of your Observer too ? Maybe the onError is called, but this is this code which crash your app.

Comment: If i comment out those rows where I do anything with Throwable e in onError() than it everything is ok. It must be the DialogManager class so probably it is another error.. not shown in the right place by logcat..

Comment: Agreed on that - the logcat output you pasted is definitely the Retrofit log, it's got the begin/end lines there.

Comment: I just added two plus exception It thrown if I remove some static modifier ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may be running into an issue has been fixed as of RxJava 1.0:

[TrampolineScheduler NullPointerException](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/1702)

Comment: I'm using rxjava's android module, now the newest on jCenter is 0.20.7 
dependency:  compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.20.7'

Comment: The new version of [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) has a different identifier - compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'. You'll need to upgrade your RxJava core modules to 1.0 as well.

Comment: This will be the problem I think. @AdamS I'm not sure what you mean "You'll need to upgrade your RxJava core modules to 1.0 as well." By the way thanks for your answers.

Comment: I am using RxJava 1.1.0 & RxAndroid 1.1.0 and facing the same issue!

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to build your own Observable with Retrofit, as Retrofit can directly return Observable:

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

> Retrofit also integrates RxJava to support methods with a return type
>   of rx.Observable
>
> @GET("/user/{id}/photo") Observable getUserPhoto(@Path("id")
>   int id);

(You won't have to handle errors by yourself)

Can you post the stacktrace of your crash ? As I think like you, that your application shouldn't crash.

Comment: Thanks, I just learnt something goood, I modified the code, like you advised, cut out all my Observable, and modified:
Observable<User> getUser(@Field("username") String userName, @Field("password") String password);
But the problem still occurs. Error is not handled, app crashes. I think it is not the Retrofit's problem, but RX.
And added the stacktrace.

Comment: By the way, what if I'd like to do something with the object before I handle it over to Observable? --> like here, at login(username, pass) --> I'd like to save the 'credentials' into the user object, and it is good to write it only once, not all the login places in the app. So here this Observable can operate like super function before telling the LoginScreen that something has happend.